# Swift Library for Access API

Tags: android, ios, api

I'm new in iOS development. I have a little experience in Android development and wanna to learn iOS development. In Android i use Retrofit library to access API.

And now i want to know kind of library for access API. I want to discuss about API library that have good performance, easy to use, and easy to understand. yeah of course i already try to find it and i get it :

https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/restkit-tutorial-how-to-fetch-data-from-an-api-into-core-data-9326af750e10

But i need more idea about library for access API, can anyone help me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can [Alamofire](https://cocoapods.org/pods/Alamofire) in ios.

```
 Alamofire.request("https://httpbin.org/get").responseJSON { response in
    print(response.request)  // original URL request
    print(response.response) // HTTP URL response
    print(response.data)     // server data
    print(response.result)   // result of response serialization

    if let JSON = response.result.value {
        print("JSON: \(JSON)")
    }
}
```

Comment: How if the API using token to access it?

Comment: use HTTPHeaders

Comment: I already try this library but i don't understand add this library to my project. Can you help me explain how to add this library to project?

Answer (score 5):

Even though Alamofire might seem like a good choice for networking, the native [URLSession](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession) along with the [Codable protocol](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types) provide the same functionality without adding any dependencies to your project.

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
    // Handle data, response, and error
}

task.resume()
```

Answer (score 2):

In iOS, the only library that's ruling on networking is [Aalmofire](https://cocoapods.org/pods/Alamofire). It simplifies all your networking calls struggles. It provides simple methods to access data from the server. **Alamofire** is in **swift**. If you want to create a project in objective C, the same library available in **Objective C** as [AFNetworking](https://cocoapods.org/pods/AFNetworking).

Below is the example of writing api calls:

```
let url = ""
let headers    = [ "Content-Type" : "application/json"]
let para : Parameters = [ "data" : JSONObject]
Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: para, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers : headers)
    .responseJSON { response in

        print(response)
        print(response.result)

}
```

**Note:** As you are a beginner I didn't tell about **URLSessions**(provided by Apple) which is the perfect way of writing API calls. But it's a very good choice in future.

Comment: If you are using access token in the header. Just simply add one more fied in header and send it.

Answer (score 0):

- [URLSession](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession) built-in possibility
- [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) is an Objective-C networking library
- [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) uses AFNetworking inside but it is written in Swift
- [SDWebImage](https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage) image downloader with cache support